# Gradle Failing when generating flutter apk in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I'm trying to generate an apk from my flutter project , so basically  i go to tools -> flutter
-> Open for editing in android studio , then i open android studio in new window , the issue is that my gradle is failing and i don't understand why , if anyone can please help me

- I have screeshots below to show the issue
- Flutter Side

[image]

- Android Side

[image]

PS : The flutter code works fine as i'm able to install and run the app , this issue happens when
i try to build an apk .

Comment: open build tab and add the error here

Comment: There is no error cause i'm not using studio for android , the error just happens when i open android studio from flutter side to generate apk on android side

Comment: Go to Build -> Generate APK and check if you get the error or apk is build. In case the Generate APK is disabled, open any dart file from your project then go to build -> generate apk